# Is there an equivalent of speakableName for voice triggers?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

When creating a contact you can set a a speakable name for names that aren't phonetic with the speakableName attribute. My company name is not phonetic, so I am wondering if there is an equivalent option to use with voice triggers for launching the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voice triggers themselves should be phrases relating to general tasks, such as "play a game" or "send a message", without branding information in them.

But it sounds like what you might need is a way to provide a speakable name for the activity or service that is bound to the voice trigger, so that if multiple Glassware use the same voice trigger, you are able to speak the name of your company/application in the disambiguation menu that appears. This isn't supported currently, but feel free to file a feature request in our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).